# Benefits of currying in Scala

Tags: scala

I wanted to clarify benefits about currying in scala. According to "Programming in Scala Second Edition" - "currying A way to write functions with multiple parameter lists. For instance
`def f(x: Int)(y: Int)` is a curried function with two parameter
lists. A curried function is applied by passing several arguments
lists, as in: `f(3)(4)`. However, it is also possible to write a partial
application of a curried function, such as `f(3)." "c"`

One benefit connected with creation partially applied functions like this

```
def multiplyCurried(x: Int)(y: Int) = x * y 
def multiply2 = multiplyCurried(2) _
```

But we also can use  partially applied functions without currying

```
def multiplyCurried(x: Int,y: Int) 
def multiply2 = multiplyCurried(2, _)
```

Could you please give a few example, where currying will show benefits ?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660852/why-does-currying-in-scala-need-multiple-parameter-lists?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between multiple parameters lists and multiple parameters per list in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803211/whats-the-difference-between-multiple-parameters-lists-and-multiple-parameters) In particular see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6803909/699224) which discusses benefits.

Answer (score 1):

Curry functions become really useful when you have implicit parameters.

Take for example the map function on futures:

```
map[S](f: (T) ⇒ S)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[S]
```

The second parameter is implicit, and this definition allows you to write expressions like

```
val f2 = f1.map(x => x)
```

when you have the implicit value in scope.

Another place where curry is useful is a common pattern in the Scala code where you would like to pass a function to a method (it may be a callback function, for instance).

Take for example the "loan" pattern for input streams, that allow you to use a stream without thinking about proper closing the resource

```
def withInputStream[T](opener: => InputStream)(f: InputStream => T): T = ...

withInputStream(new InputStream("hello.txt")) { inputStream =>
  readLines(inputStream)
}
```

This kind of syntax makes the code clearer in a lot of cases

Answer (score 0):

From Coursera course:

Assume you have these functions:

```
def sum(f:Int=>Int, a:Int, b:Int) = f(a) + f(b)
def sumInts(a:Int,b:Int)=sum(x=>x,a,b)
def sumCubes(a:Int,b:Int)=sum(x=>x*x*x,a,b)
```

Change sum into a function that returns another function:

```
def sum(f:Int=>Int):(Int,Int)=>Int={
   def sumF(a:Int,b:Int):Int= 
      if(a>b) 0 else f(a)+ sumF(a+1,b)
   sumF
  }
```

now we can define the functions we had in following way:

```
def sumInts=sum(x=>x)
def sumCubes=sum(x=>x*x*x)
```

Now we can use it in simple way:

```
sumInt(10,11) + sumCubes(3,4)
```

Now we have these sumInt and sumCubes that we want to avoid them:

```
sum(cube)(3,4)
```

so currying coming to help to not write nested function in functional programming, let redefine sum:

```
def sum(f:Int=>Int)(a:Int,b:Int):Int=
  if(a>b) 0 else f(a)+sum(f)(a+1,b)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but we can do the same things with high order function without currying if I`m not mistaken.